# Cordova: Cannot add ios platform

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

After calling `cordova platforms add ios` I get "Xcode is (probably) not installed, specifically the command 'xcode build' is unavailable." I tried to reinstall Xcode, but nothing helped. I also cannot call `xcode-select` (-bash: xcode-select: command not found).

My Xcode version is 5.0.2. Despite all these errors it works fine but I cannot add an ios platform to my cordova project. Can you help me?

Comment: To submit an app to the AppStore you need at least Xcode 5.1

Comment: I tried to install newer version of Xcode but it's still not working. I need a solution how to fix `xcode-select`

Comment: After installing Xcode did you start Xcode, since after starting Xcode it will update your system.

Comment: Yes, I did. Still same errors.

Comment: Can you post you output of `echo $path`

Comment: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:usr/local/bin`

Comment: You could just try and install the command line tools from the developer website: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-

Comment: I just installed Command Line Tools but it did not help. Still same errors and same echo $PATH

Comment: the `xcode-select` should be installed in the `/usr/bin`